# SAPUI5 Planning Calendar Appointment disappears after Dialog closure

Tags: sapui5

I am working on a UI5 application that makes use of the Planning Calendar component in connection with an ODataModel (v2). The short description of my issue is that appointments disappear from the calendar when the following sequence of events are enacted:

1. Click on an appointment in the calendar. This will cause a Dialog to be opened for viewing of appointment details and possible editing. Then ...
2. Close the dialog. Then ...
3. Move the calendar display to a different week. Then ...
4. Return to the original week. Then ...
5. The appointment that had been selected earlier is now gone.

Here are the details. An XML view is being used with the Planning Calendar instantiated like this:

```
<PlanningCalendar id="Calendar" class="calendar" viewKey="Week"
                  rows="{path: 'clndr>CalToRow', templateShareable:false}"
                  appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
                  showEmptyIntervalHeaders="true"
                  stickyHeader="true"
                  appointmentSelect="onAptSlct"
                  intervalSelect="onIntrvlSlct"
                  viewChange="onVwChng"
                  width="100%">
```

... such that a function, "onAptSlct", will be run when an appointment is selected. This function opens a Dialog component that is contained in a fragment that has been loaded and added as a dependent of the view when the program was initialized. Within the onAptSlct function and prior to opening the Dialog, the following code is run for the sake of binding the appointment data to Dialog for display:

```
onAptSlct: function (oEvent) {
    var apptmnt = oEvent.getParameter('appointment');
    var sKey = apptmnt.getKey();
    global.oAppointmentDialog.bindElement("clndr>/SchedAptSet('" + sKey + "')");
    ...
    global.oAppointmentDialog.open();
}
```

The dialog loads without error, correctly displaying the appointment data.

When I comment out the "global.oAppointmentDialog.bindElement("clndr>/SchedAptSet('" + sKey + "')");" line of code, the Dialog opens without the data and closing it and the appointment continues to be on display in the calendar, even after moving to another week and back again. So, clearly there is some issue with the Planning Calendar and the use of the bindElement method. I have even tried copying the data to a JSONModel and binding to that instead, but the appointment still disappears as when binding to the ODataModel. I've also examined the model's data contents before and after and the appointment is still there.

Does anyone know what is going on here and what to do about it? Why is the binding to the calendar of the given appointment being broken by also binding it to the Dialog? Must I somehow save off the calendar binding information and use it to restore the appointment to the calendar after closing the dialog? That hardly seems like the way this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that the dialog is still bound to the element after being closed (in case you just closed it) - which may or may not be an interference.

other thing to try is

```
onAptSlct: function (oEvent) {
    var oSource = oEvent.getSource()
    var oBindingContext = oSource.getBindingContext("clndr")
    global.oAppointmentDialog.setBindingContext(oBindingContext, "clndr");
    ...
    global.oAppointmentDialog.open();
}
```

(keep in mind that I wrote that off-hand, so check syntax, etc.)

the difference to your code is that the dialog is now bound to *same binding context* as the appointment in the planning calendar, rather than to *same absolute path within the model*

Comment: Isn't a context just the combination of a model instance and an absolute path?